# Change background color of office 2013

Tags: word-2013-preview, office-2013-preview

It looks very white all of the time, and while this look great when it is the only thing on the screen, when it is side by side with another process, this can be confusing.

How can I change this setting?

**Note:** I am aware of the different themes that are built in, but they seem to only change the top bar area, and even then, they do not change the color.

Comment: I think it's intentional, based on the reviews I've read. Very "Metro".

Comment: this will only work if you are signed into Windows Live. Even then, it only enhances the appearance of the ribbon.

Answer (score 4):

For the Office 2013 production (RTM) version:

1. Go to the File tab
2. Go to Options
3. Choose the General option on the left
4. In the dialog, find the "Office Theme" dropdown item
5. Choose between White, Light Gray, and Dark Gray

[image]

Comment: I'm with you up to #4. Any chance you could screenshot it?

Comment: I don't have the "office background" available to me :( Is it a per-build, per app?

Comment: This appears to be the only choice of theme at the moment..white,grey or dark gray bars at top and side. However, IMO it's not really good enough...it's still all too bright...everything seems to blend into one  white/grey mess

Answer (score 1):

I think the Office Bkgnds are only available if you use an online outlook account.  If you have a local user acct the bkgnds are not available.

Comment: do you have a source?

Comment: @soandos: The source (on the contrary) is in the screenshot above (in the answer by cbanswer22). The checkbox "*Always use these values regardless...*". Perhaps user194186 hasn't that checkbox checked!