# How to change the theme of only one Office program

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, themes

I can change the theme of an Office program (say Word) by the instructions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/449743/change-background-color-of-office-2013), and it works perfectly.  However, if I then open another Office program (maybe Excel), the theme has changed in that program too.

How do I change the theme of Office programs individually?

I am on Windows 7 64-bit with Office 2010.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is **not** possible with on-board equipment. see [answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/change-office-theme-for-onenote-only/9a26da54-d6d0-470d-93c3-91c115ec69d6)